# How to get REF CURSOR data from Oracle store procedure by PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I want to use procedure multiple times to get many table select from oracle database

My Oracle procedure

```sql
PROCEDURE getInfo(
  Status   IN  VARCHAR2,
  P_CUR    OUT REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN P_CUR FOR
    SELECT      *
    FROM        TABLE
    WHERE       TABLE.STATUS = Status
END;
```

Here is my Java call the the procedure. It doesn't work, I can not set registerOutParameter for PreparedStatement to get the cursor data.

```java
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
pstmt = cnn.prepareCall("{call " + schemaName + ".LOC_EXCHANGE.getInfo(?,?)}");
for (Entity entity : ListEntity) {
    int i = 1;
    pstmt.setString(i++, entity.getTxnId());
    pstmt.registerOutParameter(i, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
cnn.commit();
rs = (ResultSet) pstmt.getObject(i);
```

Comment: What is the error you get? As an aside, I'd be surprised if you'd get any cursor than the one from the last execute (if at all) when you use batch execute. This isn't what batch execute is for. Though I might be wrong, as I don't regularly work with Oracle.

Comment: Also, `registerOutParameter` isn't defined in `PreparedStatement`, you need to use `CallableStatement` (the actual type returned by `prepareCall`)

Answer (score 0):

#### Fetching the data in bulk rather than in batch

I don't think you can batch those calls. You could probably do an anonymous block, instead:

```sql
BEGIN
  LOC_EXCHANGE.getInfo(?, ?);
  LOC_EXCHANGE.getInfo(?, ?);
  LOC_EXCHANGE.getInfo(?, ?);
  ...
END;
```

#### Avoiding N+1

Personally, I think you're producing an N+1 problem here. rather than fetching data for each individual `entity.getTxnId()`, how about refactoring your `getInfo()` procedure to allow for returning data for a list of txnids? Do this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE txnids AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

And then declare:

```sql
PROCEDURE getInfo(
  Status   IN  txnids ,
  P_CUR    OUT REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN P_CUR FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE TABLE.STATUS IN (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE (Status)
  )
  ORDER BY TABLE.STATUS
END;
```

Since you're projecting `*`, you'll still be able to access the `STATUS` column in order to group data in the client, after fetching it all.